# How can I reduce the size of a partition in Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition

I have a smaller SSD that I'd like to use for my dev server. The SSD is smaller than the current OS partition. I'd like to reduce the size of the partition so that I can copy the image over to the SSD and run off of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into Server Manager, expand the Storage node, select Disk Management in the right pane, right click the disk you want to shrink in the right pane, and select the Shrink Volume item in the context menu.